# C++ : unresolved overloaded function when using function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
  int getMsg(int i)
  {
    return i + 1;
  }
};

class A
{
  B b;
public:
  void run()
  {
    taunt(b.getMsg);
  }

  void taunt(int (*msg)(int))
  {
    cout << (*msg)(1) << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.run();
}
```

The above code has a class B inside a class A, and class A has a method taunt that takes a function as an argument. class B's getMsg is passed into taunt...The above code generated the following error message: "error: no matching function for call to 'A::taunt()'"

What's causing the error message in the above code? Am I missing something?

Update:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
  int getMsg(int i)
  {
    return i + 1;
  }
};

class A
{
  B b;
public:
  void run()
  {
    taunt(b.getMsg);
  }

  void taunt(int (B::*msg)(int))
  {
    cout << (*msg)(1) << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.run();
}
```

t.cpp: In member function 'void A::run()':
Line 19: error: no matching function for call to 'A::taunt()'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

I'm still getting the same error after changing (*msg)(int) to (B::*msg)(int)

Comment: You can't use member function pointers like that in C++. Try googling it, there are plenty of articles about it out there.

Comment: In one place you're passing an `int` where an `int(*)(int)` is expected, and in another you're passing an `int(B::*)(int)` where an `int(*)(int)` is expected; why would you _expect_ this to work?

Comment: I just noticed that...and I just fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b.getMsg` is not the correct way to form a pointer to member, you need `&B::getMsg`.

`(*msg)(1)` is not the correct way to call a function through a pointer to member you need to specify an object to call the function on, e.g. (using a temporary) `(B().*msg)(1)`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: The `&` is required. ISO/IEC 14882:2011 5.3.1 / 4: "A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a _qualified-id_ not enclosed in parentheses."

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right, thanks for the correction. I'd +1 you again if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do such things in OOP is to use interfaces so all you need to do is to define an interface and implement it in B class after that pass the pointer of instance which implements this interface to your method in class A.

```
class IB{
public:
 virtual void doSomething()=0;
};

class B: public IB{
public:
 virtual void doSomething(){...}
};

class A{
public:
 void doSomethingWithB(IB* b){b->doSomething();}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in VS 2010.  The output is the same on all lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class A
{
public:
    int foo(int a, float b)
    {
        return int(a*b);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A temp;

    int x = 5;
    float y = 3.5;

    auto a = std::mem_fn(&A::foo);
    cout << a(&temp, x, y) << endl;

    auto b = std::bind(a, &temp, x, y);
    cout << b() << endl;

    auto c = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&A::foo), &temp, _1, y);
    cout << c(5) << endl;
}
```

Basically, you use `std::mem_fn` to get your callable object for the member function, and then `std::bind` if you want to bind additional parameters, including the object pointer itself.  I'm pretty sure there's a way to use `std::ref` to encapsulate a reference to the object too if you'd prefer that.  I also included the `_1` forwarding marker just for another way to specify some parameters in the bind, but not others.  You could even specify everything BUT the class instance if you wanted the same parameters to everything but have it work on different objects.  Up to you.

If you'd rather use `boost::bind` it recognizes member functions and you can just put it all on one line a bit to be a bit shorter: `auto e = boost::bind(&A::foo, &temp, x, y)` but obviously it's not much more to use completely std C++11 calls either.